# postion border image below the div

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to put a border image on the right side of div. And I've succeeded in doing that. But the problem is, I want the border image to stretch a little bit below the div. Is it possible to increase the height of the border image? Or should I just float the image next to the div and how should I do that?

Here's a [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/qu2odas4/1/)

```css
div{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#EA6E0E;
    border-image-slice: 0 31 0 0; 
    border-image-width: 0px 20px 0px 0px; 
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch; 
    border-image-source: url("http://i.imgur.com/pN8TPVw.jpg?1");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Strech to which direction?

Comment: a bit below the div. Like somehow increase the height of the border image

Comment: Sort of, using `padding-bottom` and `background-clip: content-box;`, but it seems to introduce another problem at the top (that I haven't worked out, which is why it's not an answer): [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qu2odas4/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, you should play with the `border-image-outset` property, that([**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-outset))

> describes by which amount the border image area extends beyond the border box.

The definition for a four parameter value is:

> border-image-outset: *top right bottom left*

So, changing the third parameter in your case would extend the border a little further down:

```
div{
    /* ... */

    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 20px 0px; 

    /* ... */
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qu2odas4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

A border will always be at the full length of the containing box (the height of the element plus its padding), it can't be controlled except for adjusting the height of the element to which it applies.

You can reach your goal by using a span after the div:

```
<div></div>
<span class="divider"></span>

span {
height: 5em;
border:.../your border
}
```